# gdb in docker container returns "ptrace: Operation not permitted."

Tags: c++, docker, centos, gdb, fedora

I've checked `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` in the container and on the host - both report the value as zero but when attached to pid one gdb reports

```
Reading symbols from /opt/my-web-proxy/bin/my-web-proxy...done.
Attaching to program: /opt/my-web-proxy/bin/my-web-proxy, process 1
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
```

I've also tried attached to the container with the privileged flag

```
docker exec --privileged -it mywebproxy_my-proxy_1 /bin/bash
```

Host OS is Fedora 25 with docker from their repos and container is a official centos6.8

Comment: Nothing in host dmesg output? It might be blocked by SELinux, check here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/SELinuxDenyPtrace

Comment: looks like https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21051

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I discovered the answer - the container needs to be started with strace capabilities

Adding this to my docker-compose.yml file allows GDB to work

```
cap_add:
    - SYS_PTRACE
```

Or it can also be passed on the docker command line with `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE`

Comment: This is also relevant when trying to take a heap dump for a java program with jmap or jvisualvm and getting `sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ..) failed for 1: Operation not permitted` as an error

Comment: In addition I had to use `--priviliged`